# How to trigger the custom attribute method before and after execution of method c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, custom-attributes, data-caching

I want to design a automated way for saving/retrieving the data from `cache`. This is how I want to design the architecture for it.

There would be 2 class libraries

> **DB.DataAccess**        -> This layer will execute the sp/quires by using
>                             ado.net to access the data from database
>
> **DB.DataDistributor**   -> This will be a middle tier between db and 
>                           presentation layer call the DB.DataAccess to get the data

in DB.DataDistributor I want to automate the data caching like this way by using custom attribute.

```
namespace DB.DataDistributor
{
    public class MessageManager
    {


        [CachDataAttribute(CacheKey = CacheKeys.Message, CacheDataType = typeof(List<Message>))]
        public List<Message> GetMessages()
        {
            DB.DataAccess.MesssageManager msgManager = null;
            try
            {
                msgManager = new DB.DataAccess.MesssageManager();
                var messages = msgManager.GetMessages();
                return messages;
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                throw;
            }
            finally
            {
                msgManager = null;
            }
        }


    }
}

namespace DB.DataDistributor
{
    [AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Method)]
    internal class DataCachingFilterAttribute : Attribute
    {
        public CacheKeys CacheKey { get; set; }
        public Type CacheDataType { get; set; }

        public void SetCache()
        {
            //this method should call after execution of method where DataCachingFilterAttribute has attached 
        }

        public void GetCache()
        {
            //this method should call before execution of method where DataCachingFilterAttribute has attached
            //here I will check if data available in cache then will return data from cache and do not call the achtual method 
        }
    }

    public enum CacheKeys
    {
        Message
    }
}
```

- Whenever presentation layer calls `GetMessages` method of
  `DB.DataDistributor.MessageManager` system should execute the
  `GetCache()` method of `DataCachingFilterAttribute` class if data
  found in cache then the actual method `GetMessages` should not be
  executed and data return directally from cache else called the `GetMessages` and return the data from there.
- Right after result returned from `GetMessages` the `SetCache` method of
  `DataCachingFilterAttribute` should call to set the result in cache.

This is my thought to automate the data caching but I am not getting how to trigger the `DataCachingFilterAttribute` methods before and after `GetMessages` method execution.

If anyone has any idea or other good approach to automate the caching please share.

Comment: Maybe use [Action filters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/older-versions-1/controllers-and-routing/understanding-action-filters-cs) instead of custom attribute (especially if it's asp.net project?

Comment: That's not how attributes work *in general*. They don't get to run extra code. There are some frameworks (asp.net already mentioned) with some special support for special attributes to make things like this happen. There are also generic frameworks (e.g. PostSharp) that will do "code weaving" to allow you to put cross-cutting concerns into attributes. But there's nothing in bog-standard .NET. The ones in asp.net tend to be oriented at the more Action/Url sort of level rather than down in the dependencies.